# Set a number in Remix payable source

Tags: solidity, remix, ico, payable

There's `buyprice` on function `buy` and `sellprice` on function `sell`.  I would like to set up

```
1 ETH =  10000 (SYMBOL)
0.1 ETH = 1000 (SYMBOL)
0.01 ETH = 100 (SYMBOL)
0.001 ETH = 10 (SYMBOL)
```

How can I set a number on `buyprice` and `sellprice`?  Even if i calculated it, it doesn't work at all

```solidity
function buy() payable returns (uint amount) {
  amount = msg.value / buyPrice;      // calculates the amount
  require(balanceOf[this] >= amount); // checks if it has enough to sell
  balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;    // adds the amount to buyer's balance
  balanceOf[this] -= amount;          // subtracts amount from seller's balance
  Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount); // execute an event reflecting the change
  return amount;                      // ends function and returns
}

function sell(uint amount) returns (uint revenue) {
  require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount); // checks if the sender has enough to sell
  balanceOf[this] += amount;                // adds the amount to owner's balance
  balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;          // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
  revenue = amount * sellPrice;
  msg.sender.transfer(revenue);             // sends ether to the seller: it's important to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
  Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);       // executes an event reflecting on the change
  return revenue;                           // ends function and returns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be part of the ethereum website example, the whole code is posted there. The price can be set in the constructor

```
contract Mycontract{
    uint public sellprice;
    uint public buyprice;
    address public admin;

    constructor(uint _sellprice, uint _buyprice) {
        sellprice = _sellprice;
        buyprice = _buyprice;
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    function sell()...

    function buy()..


}
```

If you need the price to be changed over time, you add this function:

```
function updateprice(uint _sellprice, uint buyprice) public {
    sellprice = _sellprice;
    buyprice = _buyprice;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, however it is unclear with my main question. I will put my words in constructor but where do i have to put it in my source?
my source is down here. please check this .,
https://etherscan.io/address/0x72f3f3b2fdadd95182e26031e3ba99f0d62b5600#code

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all you need to convert all amounts to basic units.  For ether, basic unit is Wei and 1 ETH = 1e18 Wei (1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei).  So,

```
1 ETH = 1e18 Wei (1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei)
0.1 ETH = 1e17 Wei (100,000,000,000,000,000 Wei)
0.01 ETH = 1e16 Wei (10,000,000,000,000,000 Wei)
0.001 ETH = 1e15 Wei  (1,000,000,000,000,000 Wei)
```

You token seems to have 18 decimals as well, so one whole token is 1e18 basic units (BU), and

```
10000 (SYMBOL) = 1e22 BU (10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 BU)
1000 (SYMBOL) = 1e21 BU (1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 BU)
100 (SYMBOL) = 1e20 BU (100,000,000,000,000,000,000 BU)
10 (SYMBOL) = 1e19 BU (10,000,000,000,000,000,000 BU)
```

Now you may calculate your buy and sell prices in basic units:

```
tokenAmount = ethAmount / buyPrice
10000 (SYMBOL) = 1 ETH / buyPrice
1e22 BU = 1e18 Wei / buyPrice
buyPrice = 1e-4
buyPrice = 0.0001
```

The problem is that Solidity dose not support fractional numbers, so you cannot divide by 0.0001 directly.  Fortunately, you may just multiple by 10000 like this:

```
uint invertedBuyPrice = 10000;
amount = msg.value * invertedBuyPrice;
```

Now sell price:

```
ethAmount = tokenAmount * sellPrice
1 ETH = 10000 (SYMBOL) * sellPrice
1e18 Wei = 1e22 BU * sellPrice
sellPrice = 1e-4
sellPrice = 0.0001
```

Now we have the same problem, seel price is fractional and Solidity cannot deal with fractions, though the same solution works here as well:

```
invertedSellPrice = 10000;
revenue = amount / invertedSellPrice;
```